# Magento 2.2 - Want to implement blackfire for community edition

Tags: magento2.2, sql, performance

I have heard about **blackfire** php profiler and automated performance tool that can be used in three environments.

If i wanted to implement in **Magento 2.2** based website using nginx server then is it possible to add blackfire.io into it.

Need to investigate following stuffs

1. SQL query logs
2. performance issues

Went through following url but not able to find any particular guide for Magento 2 community edition.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-integrate-blackfire.html